# Have div overflow half of it through the top of its parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

I'm trying to make a good looking bottom drawer slider.

There will be a circular button fixed at the bottom of the page, that only half of it should be shown when the drawer is closed (half a circle), and click it to expand the drawer

Silly diagram :

```
  _____________________________
  |         Web Page          |
  |                           | 
  |                           |
  |           ____            |
  |__________/ /\ \___________|  < Closed (bottom of browser window)

  _____________________________
  |         Web Page          | 
  |           ____            |
  |__________/ /\ \___________|  < Opened
  |          \____/           |
  |___________________________|
```

JsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ppgab/wcec9gc6/4/ (I'm using semantic ui but that isn't necessary)

How can I have only one half the button show when the drawer is closed?

**HTML**

```
<div>Page content</div>
<div id="map" class="down">
  <div>
      <i class="ui circular link expand big inverted icon"></i>
  </div>
  bottom slider content
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#map {
  background-color: #303030;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center !important;
  height: 4%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
}
```

**JavaScript/jQuery**

```
$('.icon').click(function() {

  if ($("#map").hasClass("down")) {
    $("#map").removeClass("down");
    $("#map").animate({
      height: "50%"
    }, 600);

  } else {

    $("#map").animate({
      height: "4%"
    }, 350);
    $("#map").addClass("down");
  }

});
```

Would be even better if using percentage dimensions.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Can you include the relevant code in the question?

Comment: this what you're going for? https://jsfiddle.net/wcec9gc6/5/

Comment: @MichaelCoker yes, except only half the button should be visible when closed, also no transparency

Comment: Don't animate the height - Animate e.g. margin instead.

Comment: @LukeBriggs the content is going to be a webmap, it worked when I tried it in an earlier version http://jsfiddle.net/ppgab/jbt70gsh/2/

Comment: If you have any bottom positioned elements in there though, they'll get squashed upwards (as well as being lower in performance from a flow point of view).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the effect you wanted, I made three changes:

#### 1. Move the icon upwards

You can do this with a simple `margin-top: 28px` to move it halfway up (it has a total height and padding of 56px) or use `transform: translateY(-50%)` (for the bonus points).

#### 2. Prevent transparency of icon.

Transparency is caused by an `overflow: hidden` in the `#map` element caused by the `animate()` jQuery function. Add a `overflow: visible` to the `#map` element.

#### 3. Totally hide the `#map`

Simply change `height` to 0 in both the CSS and the JS.

---

In summary:

```js
$('.icon').click(function() {

  if ($("#map").hasClass("down")) {
    $("#map").removeClass("down");
    $("#map").animate({
      height: "50%"
    }, 600);

  } else {

    $("#map").animate({
      height: "0%"
    }, 350);
    $("#map").addClass("down");
  }

});
```

```css
#map {
  background: #303030;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center !important;
  height: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: visible !important;
}
i {
  margin-top: -28px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Page content</div>

<div id="map" class="down">
  <div>
    <i class="ui circular link expand big inverted icon"></i>
  </div>
  bottom slider content
</div>
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wcec9gc6/7/)

Comment: The button is still in flow which results in a probably unwanted gap. Animating height is generally a bad idea too.

Comment: Actually I think the opacity from the button comes from the semantic ui library, I guess a way would be to add a matching circular div behind it

Comment: [Here's a fork](https://jsfiddle.net/nhLe0ngg/) which animates bottom instead of height and doesn't have that gap (because the button is now out of flow).

Comment: I will use Luke's answer as he seems very convicing about that issue

Comment: Just for fun, a [no clicking required CSS only version](https://jsfiddle.net/zsw42vza/) too :)

Comment: This is just optional, but how can I make the button be on top of its parent? In my actual context : https://jsfiddle.net/ppgab/na12wgbh/2/ it gets cut

Comment: @Mojimi You'd use a positive z-index rather than a negative one, e.g. `z-index:1`. Alternatively, position the actual map element (_not_ meaning #map - with e.g. position:absolute) - that'll generate a new "stacking context".

Answer (score 2):

Try this snippet, I got rid of the icon and changed the background color.

```js
$('#circle').click(function() {

  if ($("#map").hasClass("down")) {
    $("#map").removeClass("down");
    $("#map").animate({
      height: "50%"
    }, 600);

  } else {

    $("#map").animate({
      height: "0%"
    }, 350);
    $("#map").addClass("down");
  }

});
```

```css
#map {
  overflow: visible !important;
  background: #303030;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center !important;
  height: 0%;
  bottom: 0;
  position: fixed;
  color: #fff;
}

#circle {
  background-color: #303030;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  margin: -35px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Page content</div>

<div id="map" class="down">
  <div>
      <div id="circle">
      
      </div>
  </div>
  bottom slider content
</div>
```

Comment: @Zeus, I see, you edited my answer to change `white` to `#fff`. Is there a reason that `#fff` is better?

Comment: it looks much better with hex codes ;) it's looks more "programatical"

Answer (score 1):

Position your `.icon` element absolutely inside your `#map` div

**CSS**

```
.icon {
    position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer all of the parts of the question.